# Logging Build messages with MSBuild 4.0

Tags: c#, msbuild-4.0

I am using MsBuild 4.0 in code, like so:

```
 var globalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(solutionPathAbsolute, globalProperties, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
 var pc = new ProjectCollection();

 var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new BuildParameters(pc), buildRequest);
```

Note how this API is completely different from MsBuild 3.5... How does one hook in a logger to recieve detailed build messages with the new API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [BeginBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.execution.buildmanager.beginbuild?view=netframework-4.7.2#Microsoft_Build_Execution_BuildManager_BeginBuild_Microsoft_Build_Execution_BuildParameters_) method on the BuildManager allows you to pass in a set of [BuildParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.execution.buildparameters?view=netframework-4.7.2) which includes a Loggers property.

Comment: Does MSBuild expose an API for start a build which it threads internally or does managing a thread to handle building seperate from the application at large need to be done by the application?

Comment: @James I suggest you create a new question here on the site to get your answer if it hasn't already been asked.

Comment: Hey @James could you tell me something about the asynchronous API?