# how to create an exe file from my created file(.cs file)?

Tags: c#, winforms

This C# code is for running a Winform application that I have merged together. I want to create an exe file from that C# code.

How can this be done?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public static class Program
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}

public class Form1 : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.Text = "Form1";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using a C# compiler (`csc.exe`)?

Comment: I am presuming that you don't have visual studio ? Go get Visual C# Express 2010 from Microsoft. Its free!

Comment: sorry ... but I know what are you saying to me ... so i know IDE like VS or anything and how to use it !!!

I want that my C# winform produce a exe file! OK?! ... actually ... I want to produce exe file from my project(windows form application) !!! ... I'm creating a program like visual studio can create exe file... but so simpler than VS!!!

I want some code to produce exe file from my file that i wrote in my first post!!!!

Comment: I think you want to build C# code from your app. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264682/running-msbuild-programmatically

Answer (score 8):

You can use csc compiler and write this in console (path to csc.exe may vary), I'm assuming that your code file name is program.cs:

> ```
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe /t:winexe program.cs
> ```

Executable file will be named program.exe

If you want to do this from C# code (If I understand correctly what you want to do), you can do it in this way:

Build and execute C# console application with this code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\csc.exe", "/t:winexe program.cs");
}
```

Comment: thanx ... how to use this using C# code?!

Comment: I don't know exactly where do you want use this C# code, I've written some code and updated my post, maybe this will help you.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get any executable. what is the generated .exe path?

Comment: @SGG for me it's generated in the path where the `csc.exe` it's called... so probably if you call `csc.exe` using the full `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v...\` path, the generated `.exe` will be there.

Answer (score -1):

You need a compiler or an IDE with an inbuilt compiler

Try using Microsoft Visual C# Express, it's free

Comment: He already has the compiler he would have to call it by hand.  Since he is asking how to do that its safe to say thats not an option :-)

Comment: your reply is not for my problem at all!!! ... because I want produce exe file from that file inside my project!!!