# MSBuild threw error: "... task could not be instantiated from the assembly"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

**EDIT:** Never mind, it turns that out the task does not actually implement the `Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask` interface. I had made the erroneous assumption that it did. D'oh!

I use Visual Studio 2015.

Relevant code:

```
string solutionFilePath = args.Single();

var fileLogger = new FileLogger { Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Detailed, Parameters = @"logfile=C:\MSBuildResults.txt" };
var projectCollection = new ProjectCollection {DefaultToolsVersion = "14.0"};
var buildParameters = new BuildParameters(projectCollection) { Loggers = new List<ILogger> { fileLogger } };

var globalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Configuration", "Debug" }, { "Platform", "Any CPU" } };
var buildRequestData = new BuildRequestData(solutionFilePath,
                                            globalProperties,
                                            targetsToBuild: new[] { "Build" },
                                            toolsVersion: "14.0",
                                            hostServices: null);

BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParameters, buildRequestData);
```

`buildResult.OverallResult` is `BuildResultCode.Failure`, with error messages like the following printed to my log file:

> C:\Workspaces\SomeProject.csproj(67,5): error MSB4127: The "DummyTask"
>   task could not be instantiated from the assembly
>   "\networkDrive\Dummy.dll". Please verify the task assembly has been
>   built using the same version of the Microsoft.Build.Framework assembly
>   as the one installed on your computer and that your host application
>   is not missing a binding redirect for Microsoft.Build.Framework.
>   Unable to cast object of type 'DummyTask' to type
>   'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask'.

Following the advice [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2772a075-4e2f-42af-9e7a-2228b794368e/msbuild-crashes-with-a-message-task-could-not-be-instantiated-exception?forum=msbuild), I added the `<bindingRedirect>` tag in the `.exe.config` file of my program. The same error messages were thrown nonetheless.

Instead of using `Microsoft.Build` libraries, I decided to invoke `MSBuild.exe` using `Process.Start()` (which I know is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7264756/3559686)):

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe") 
{
      Arguments = $"{solutionFilePath} /t:Build",
      RedirectStandardOutput = false,
      UseShellExecute = true,
      CreateNoWindow = false
};
var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

process.WaitForExit();            
process.Close();
```

This time, the build was successful and the process ran to completion with exit code 0.

What did I do wrong when using `Microsoft.Build` libraries to build my solution? What should I do instead to ensure that the build succeeds when I use `BuildManager`?

Let me know if you need any more information to help me with my issue.

Comment: *Unable to cast object of type 'DummyTask' to type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask'.*  Well?  Does it implement ITask?

Comment: @Will I made the assumption that it did, but now I have just checked and realised that it actually doesn't. D'oh!

Comment: Well, there's yer problem...