# Generate Winforms Project .exe programmatically from within a Winforms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, build, exe

I have a requirement to build a container C# WinForm Application which will spit out .exe files of another WinForm Application on a button click event.

For eg: I have one Winform App named **ProjectA** which accepts one startup argument. Now I have a container WinForm App named **ProjectB**. I want to generate **ProjectA.exe** programmatically within ProjectB by passing the required parameter to ProjectA app on the button click.

Could not find anything relevant about this on Google. Can anyone throw in some light to achieve this.

Please note that both the Winforms Application must be written in C#.

I have one very vague thought of using **MSBuild** **Command** to build ProjectA which in turn will generate its .exe
However I am not too clear on this.

Comment: I can only point you in the right direction on this as it was done in a previous employer of mine. But yes you need to use MSBuild.exe. E.g. C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe. This accepts parameters for solution location, build configuration, platform etc...

Comment: Thanks @Wheels73. Do you have any references or documentation about it? I have never used MSBuild till now. So I am a bit new to this whole thing.

Comment: Nope sorry. As i said, it was an old company. I've just done a quick search. This topic is covered on this site. try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264682/running-msbuild-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to mess with MSBuild for this. You may generate your program's code as a string and then generate your executables on the fly:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/304655/how-to-programmatically-compile-code-using-c-compiler

Comment: I think this will have huge impact if we talk about scalability and maintenance of a project. Also debugging using a string will be an issue. Anyways thanks for your reply. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As an example:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe", @"d:\app1\app1.sln");
```

Another Example:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe", @"d:\app1\app1.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.0");
```

put the above code on your button click.

Comment: This sounds like just what I wanted. I am gonna try this out once and mark this as an accepted answer. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you let me know how to pass arguments to app1.sln using MSbuild.exe. Thanks

Comment: @Harshit Gandhi, if you want to learn more about MSBuild Command-Line Reference, see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311(v=vs.140).aspx).